# typescript not compiling on visual studio online tfs

Tags: typescript, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I'm using Typescript 1.7 with MVC. My typescript works and compiles locally OK.

I am using visualstudioonline TFS with continuous integration to an azure website. typescript has worked fine with this setup for a while, but now, suddenly, any new typescript files do not produce a javascript file on the server after CI. (they do on my local machine.) and if i change a TS file, the JS file does not update on the server after a CI build/deploy.

Any ideas? I tried updating to typescript 1.75 with no luck.

I have also tried using the new build service VSO offers instead of the XAML build i was using before, and it also does not compile and publish the javascript files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the new TypeScript files are getting included under a `<TypeScriptCompile` key in your project file.

> publish the javascript files.

Include the generated JavaScript files in your project. This is needed depending upon your deployment workflow e.g. azure deploy requires such assets to be a part of the project (similar to third party JavaScript files).

Comment: I checked that and they are being included. Existing files are also not being updated on the server.

Comment: @Micheal perhaps its being compiled fine. Just the compiled assets are not getting deployed

Comment: FWIW I moved away from VS build years ago : https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts/ Editing XML is not something I like doing.

Comment: with VSO publishing it for me, how do i ensure that the JS files are being published?

Comment: the JS files are not included in my project right now, but they never have been before and were working up until a day or two ago

Comment: `with VSO publishing it for me, how do i ensure that the JS files are being published` Include them in the project (as `Content`). Trust me

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and has been fixed with TypeScript 1.76. Refer to this link for details: [TypeScript v1.7 MSBuild tooling breaks web application publish](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5894)

However, since the Hosted Build Controller/Agent may don't have this version installed, you may need to deploy your own build agent/controller and install the 1.76 version on it. See this link for the information: [Typescript build tools 1.7.6 upgrade on VSO](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2198505)

Comment: Hi Eddie, do you know if this has been fixed on the hosted build controllers yet? I notice your second link still shows it as active, however a sprint released last week. I don't want to go back to old release system until this is fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the list of supported software for hosted build agents. No idea how up to date this list is kept but right now it is 5 months behind. Whether the list isn't updated or the build agents aren't I can't tell.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted#software

As of 3/16/17 the latest Typescript version is from October 2016!

```
TypeScript 2.0.6 for Visual Studio 2015
```